# Adding scaleline when using a custom projection

Tags: openlayers

I have recently started working with OL3 and now I try to add ScaleLine control to my map

```
var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine({units:'metric'});
var scaleLine = ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
    collapsible: false
    })
}).extend([
    scaleLineControl
]);
map.addControl(scaleLine);
```

When doing this I get the AssertionError: Assertion failed in Firefox

Im using proj4 and the map is using a different projection.

Isnt it possible to use scaleline with other that EPSG:4326  ?

Br
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Just create the control and add it to the map using `addControl`. You do not need to use `ol.control.defaults`.

Comment: Have you managed to get that work for you?
Because for me it doesn't help if i just do:

    var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine({units:'m'});

map.addControl(scaleLineControl);

I still get AssertionError: Assertion failed